# Forefront 2010 does not let logins using 'Public or Shared Computer'

Tags: firewall, login, microsoft-forefront-2010

I have recently inherited a Forefront TMG 2010 server, and when people try to login and select 'This is a public or shared computer' they are unable to login.  No errors, just reloads the same page.

If they select 'This is a private computer' they get in straight away.

Any ideas how to allow both to log people in?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this issue when I noticed the time on the TMG server was incorrect.  After a reboot the time on the server was out, making sure it had the correct time resolved the issue.